# Rendering generated JSON HTML Representation to HTML (vue.js — Headless)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, content-management-system, headless, kirby

currently I am trying to combine NUXT.js with a headless version of KirbyCMS.
Basically the CMS takes the data and puts it into a JSON format.

The data only contains content like Images, Texts, Galleries, Images and so on. (Basically anything from the [Kirby Editor](https://getkirby.com/plugins/getkirby/editor).

**My Problem:**
The API gives me the data in a really flat structure, and I don't know how to structure it properly, here is an example.

```
[{
    "attrs": {
        "group": "default",
        "blockClass": "",
        "rowClass": "",
        "autoLayout": true,
        "images": [{
            "filename": "bildschirmfoto-2020-07-26-um-19.10.51.png",
            "guid": "/pages/about/files/bildschirmfoto-2020-07-26-um-19.10.51.png",
            "altText": "",
            "imageClass": ""
        }]
    },
    "content": "",
    "id": "_xmyqaklgh",
    "type": "gallery"
}, {
    "attrs": {
        "group": "default",
        "images": [{
            "filename": "bildschirmfoto-2020-07-27-um-19.34.25.png",
            "guid": "/pages/about/files/bildschirmfoto-2020-07-27-um-19.34.25.png",
            "altText": "",
            "imageClass": ""
        }]
    },
    "content": "",
    "id": "_vzbpk4wlg",
    "type": "gallery"
}, {
    "attrs": [],
    "content": "Test",
    "id": "_f02i6jix4",
    "type": "ul"
}, {
    "attrs": {
        "indent": 0
    },
    "content": "Tag 2",
    "id": "_8jkbqbmsc",
    "type": "ul"
}]
```

The thing I want to do is render the elements in my vue-Component. The Main problem is, that I cannot group any of the lists, or determine which gallery should group together.

```
<div v-for="block in data" :key="block.id" class="text--element">
    <h1 v-if="block.type == 'h1'">{{ block.content }}</h1>
    <h2 v-if="block.type == 'h2'">{{ block.content }}</h2>
    <h3 v-if="block.type == 'h3'">{{ block.content }}</h3>
    <p v-if="block.type == 'paragraph'">{{ block.content }}</p>
    <ul v-if="block.type == 'ul'">
        <li> {{ block.content }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My current approach was to just iterate over the items and displaying it whether the type is correct or not. But this does not seem to be *and feel* right. Has anyone a better idea to solve this?